# Show logged user info in browser, PHP php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I want to display current user info from database after login.
Here is my code.

Controller 1 (Welcome)

```
public function getValues() {
    $this->load->model('display_model');
    $result=$this->display_model->authenticateUser();

    if($result){

        $this->session->set_userdata('id', $result['id']);

        redirect('/member/home/');
    }
    else
        redirect('/welcome/');
```

Controller 2 (member)

```
public function __construct()
{
        // Call the CI_Model constructor
        parent::__construct();

        if($this->session->userdata('id')==NULL)
        {
            redirect('/welcome/');
        }
}
public function home() {

    $this->load->view('member_home');
}
```

Model

```
public function authenticateUser(){
$name =$_POST['name'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$where=array('name'=>$name,
             'password'=>$password);

return $this->db->select('name, password, id')
                ->from('member')
                ->where($where)
                ->get()->row_array();
```

View 1 (login_view)

```
<h1>Member Login Form</h1>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('Welcome/getValues'); ?>

    Username: <br/>

<input type="text" name="name" /> <br>

Password:  <br>

<input type="password" name="password" /> <br>

<input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"/>


</form>
```

View 2: After login view (member_home)

```
<?php   
         foreach($result as $row){
            ?>
            <li><?php echo $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'];?>
                <br/><strong>Email: </strong><?php echo $row['email'];?>
            </li>
```

Now error shows 
**Message: Undefined variable: result**

How to solve it Need Help.. Thanks in Advance

Comment: change `row_array();` to `result_array();` and where are you loading your `login_view` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the $result value to your home view update the code as follows:

**Controller 1:**

```
   public function getValues() {
        $this->load->model('display_model');
        $result=$this->display_model->authenticateUser();

        if($result){

            $this->session->set_userdata('id', $result['id']);

            redirect(member/home/$result['id']);
        }
        else
            redirect('/welcome/');
```

**Controller 2:**

```
  public function __construct()
    {
            // Call the CI_Model constructor
            parent::__construct();

            if($this->session->userdata('id')==NULL)
            {
                redirect('/welcome/');
            }
    }
    public function home($id = '') {

        $data['id'] = $id;
        $this->load->view('member_home',$data);
    }
```

**NOTE:**

you must change the query result from row_array() to result_array() as you are using foreach on the view

Comment: @HasanThr please accept the answer if it worked for you